# Seedling chilli plant - not quite right

Tags: diagnosis, chili

Help - recently my tall and frowning seedling chilli plant appears to be getting new growth but the leaves either develop brown spots and die, or shrivel up.

We water it once a week, maybe a bit less.

Any ideas?!

Comment: Could you please upload some pictures of the Chilli plant in question?